# Listing Creation Control like Google Keep in an Android app

Tags: android, google-keep

[Here is the link of creating a list](https://keep.google.com/u/0/) in Google Keep app. I need this list creation control in Android.

[image]

I am searching for control of creating item listing like Google Keep Android.

Is there any third party library? If not, then give me an idea to create control like that.

Comment: You can use StaggeredGridLayoutManager with RecyclerView, it will lay your contents as masonry

Comment: Which app you are refering?

Comment: @USKMobility Google Keep App Listing creation control.

Comment: check the edit question.

Comment: check this out : https://keep.google.com/u/0/
list creation control in android like the link given.

Answer (score 1):

Irshu mention in comment to use StaggeredGridLayoutManager.A LayoutManager that lays out children in a staggered grid formation. It supports horizontal & vertical layout as well as an ability to layout children in reverse.

Staggered grids are likely to have gaps at the edges of the layout. To avoid these gaps, StaggeredGridLayoutManager can offset spans independently or move items between spans.

For more details visit: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Tutorials : http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/